# How to find manhattan distance in a continuous two-dimensional matrix?

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix, distance

Let's say my matrix is

```
7 1 2
3 5 6
4 8 9
```

The goal configuration is sorted one, as follows:

```
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
```

Using manhattan distance algorithm I can calculate distance of "7" to its destination as 2 steps, but the matrix is continuous, that is I can shift rows and columns in both directions, so "7" is just one step away from the right spot.

How to modify manhattan distance algorithm to reflect that property?

Thank you.

Comment: I think this is independent from Manhattan Distance. It's more an implementation detail. You just need to implement your data structure (or solver) to represent the torus structure.

Comment: It's hard to suggest modifying when you haven't shown your current algorithm. I suspect I'd use modulo arithmetic and allow my attempts to move `(height+1)/1` positions in all directions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the usual case, which is to say a grid without wraparound, we define the Manhattan distance from `i, j` to `r, c` as

```
abs(r-i) + abs(c-j)
```

where `abs` means absolute value.

In a wraparound grid of `n` horizontal lines (rows) and `m` vertical lines (columns), we can calculate the Manhattan distance as

```
min(abs(r-i), n-1-abs(r-i))  +  min(abs(c-j), m-1-abs(c-j))
```

where `min` is the function that takes the minimum of two values.

The reasoning behind this formula is that the distance from the first row to the last row is `n-1`. If we have a direct distance `d` between any two rows, the wraparound distance `e` is the value such that:

```
d + e = n-1

e = n-1 - d
```

[image: distance between rows with wraparound]

Now the distance between two rows is the minimum of the direct distance and the wraparound distance. We argue likewise for the distance between columns. The Manhattan distance is simply the sum of the distance between rows and the distance between columns.

Consider the following example, where we have `n = 8` rows and `m = 10` columns. We want to calculate the Manhattan distance from `(2, 7)` to `(5, 1)`.

[image: Manhattan distance example]

Without wraparound, the Manhattan distance is:

```
abs(r-i) + abs(c-j)

= abs(5-2) + abs(1-7)

= abs(3) + abs(-6)

= 3 + 6

= 9
```

With wraparound, the Manhattan distance is:

```
min(abs(r-i), n-1-abs(r-i))  +  min(abs(c-j), m-1-abs(c-j))

= min(3, 7-3) + min(6, 9-6)

= min(3, 4) + min(6, 3)

= 3 + 3

= 6
```